# Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, connection

I have setup the `Node.js v19.3.0` with `MySQL 5.7.41` using `docker 20.10.14, build a224086`

I have written the connection code in the `script.js` file but when I hit `npm start` then after 8-10 seconds it causes connection close error as below

`Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. at Protocol.end (/home/kishan/node-api-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13) at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/kishan/node-api-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28) at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/kishan/node-api-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10) at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35) at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) -------------------- at Protocol._enqueue (/home/kishan/node-api-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48) at Protocol.handshake (/home/kishan/node-api-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23) at Connection.connect (/home/kishan/node-api-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kishan/node-api-demo/config/server.js:79:5) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12) at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 { fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }`

I have created the `docker-compose.yml` and `script.js` files below.

**docker-compose.yml**

```js
version: '3'
 
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_secret_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app_db
      MYSQL_USER: db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_user_pass
    ports:
      - "6033:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2025:80
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

**script.js**

```js
var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  //host: "localhost",
  user: "db_user",
  password: "db_user_pass",
  database: "app_db",
  port: 2025,
  // connectionLimit: 15,
  // queueLimit: 30,
  // queryTimeout: 600000, 
  // connectTimeout: 1000000,
  // acquireTimeout: 1000000
});

con.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I have tried all the comment removing on the createConnection function but it didn't work

Kindly please help me to fix this out in the standard way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be connecting to the db (port 6033, not pma [2025]).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works!

Also can you please guide me on the best way to start the node ex what I should use MySQL version, MySQL packages for better connectivity between queries and structures etc...